# How can I use this Javascript data to populate table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend

I'm getting this array of variables from Meta4 ERP to populate a table.

```
        <script  type="text/javascript">
            var planDayJS = {date: 26/12/2011, planName: 2011 PT - Vacation Days, dayType: Full Day,dayStatus: ACCEPTED}
            PlannedDaysJS.push(planDay);
        </script>
        <script  type="text/javascript">
            var planDayJS = {date: 27/12/2011, planName: 2011 PT - Vacation Days, dayType: Full Day,dayStatus: ACCEPTED}
            PlannedDaysJS.push(planDay);
        </script>
        ...
        <script  type="text/javascript">
            var planDayJS = {date: 28/12/2011, planName: 2011 PT - Vacation Days, dayType: Full Day,dayStatus: ACCEPTED}
            PlannedDaysJS.push(planDay);
        </script>
        <script  type="text/javascript">
            var planDayJS = {date: 29/12/2011, planName: 2011 PT - Vacation Days, dayType: Full Day,dayStatus: ACCEPTED}
            PlannedDaysJS.push(planDay);
        </script>
```

I cant' see how I can use it.

It should be one array but it seems to me many arrays.

Any help?

Comment: It's actually a syntax error. But assuming you had quotes around the values then it would just be an array of objects. We can't tell how to use it unless you tell how you want to use it and in what context.

Comment: `PlannedDaysJS` could be your "one array"

Comment: before all `<script>` tgs `<script type='text/javascript' > 
  var PlannedDaysJS= []; 
</script>`.Then it will be available in all `script` tags

Comment: I now see the that tag in my document:

<script type="text/javascript">var PlannedDaysJS=[];</script>

But when I try to log for example "PlannedDaysJS.lenght" it returns "undifined"

Comment: Is it because it's `length` not `lenght`?

Comment: It would throw error on push if you dont have array before you get length of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of array filling. You have n objects with its parameters that you push one by one in predefined array. After that you can do with it what you like.

```js
var PlannedDaysJS = new Array();
PlannedDaysJS.push({"par1" : 1, "par2" : 2});
PlannedDaysJS.push({"par1" : 3, "par2" : 4});
PlannedDaysJS.push({"par1" : 5, "par2" : 6});
PlannedDaysJS.push({"par1" : 7, "par2" : 8});


var tblOutput = "<table border='1' width='100%'>";
for (var i=0; i<PlannedDaysJS.length; i++) {
  tblOutput += "<tr>";
  tblOutput += "<td>" + PlannedDaysJS[i].par1 + "</td>";  
  tblOutput += "<td>" + PlannedDaysJS[i].par2 + "</td>";  
  tblOutput += "</tr>";
}
tblOutput += "</table>";
document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML = tblOutput;
```

```html
<div id="tbl"></div>
```

Comment: I understand the second part, that creates the table and populates it. The problem is to extract data from the objects. If i try 

console.log(PlannedDaysJS.length); it returns 0.

Comment: Try to trace it trough browser console with brake point. You have 1 array (or you should have it) and then you add objects in it. planDayJS is object and all inside braces are object's parameters (name : value). So you have date, planName, dayType and dayStatus as parameters (all after colon is parameter value). **Place name and value for each parameter inside quotes.** PlannedDaysJS is your array of planDayJS objects. When you trace your code you will see how your  PlannedDaysJS  array get new object after each push method.